# Using @ViewChild to select an element by Class name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In this article [Create Advanced Component](https://netbasal.com/create-advanced-components-in-angular-e0655df5dde6) the author selects an element by first creating a directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.tooltip-container'
})
export class TooltipContainerDirective {}
```

And then using that directive to select the element containing the class `.tooltip-container` like this:

```
    @Component({
    template: `
        <div class="tooltip-container" [ngStyle]="{top: top}">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
        </div>
    `,
    styles: [...]
    })
    export class TooltipComponent implements OnInit {
    top : string;
    @ViewChild(TooltipContainerDirective, { read: ElementRef }) private tooltipContainer;


    }
```

Does Angular have the ability to select the `tooltipContainer` element by class name without using the directive?

Comment: No, you can't select by CSS selectors with any of the query features.

Comment: @Reactgular of course you can: https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet => Directive configuration

Comment: @Nickolaus - That is not for `@ViewChild`.

Comment: As @Nickolaus realized the author uses the directive to make the `tooltipContainer` available in `ngOnInit` instead of `ngAfterViewInit`.  Interesting and subtle distinction.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-container')` will do the job.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi I think your code should work,... 
btw. you can use the ViewChild-Selector like a CSS-Selector (so `@ViewChild('.tooltip-container')` should work as well (notice: @ViewChild will only return the first result).
Furthermore you can use `#myId` on any HTML-Element and then select the child by using `@VievChild('myId')`
But I do not think that is your problem, is it possible your are trying to access the ViewChild in `ngOnInit`?, because that won't work... the child will be available as the view is rendered therefore the first time you can access the child is `ngAfterViewInit`.

Comment: AHA!  Yes good hunch.  The tutorial author is accessing the `tooltipContainer` in `ngOnInit`, which is probably why he's using the `tooltip-container` directive to grab the `tooltipContainer ElementRef`.

Comment: Created a `<div class="test">` inside a component, then added the view child ` @ViewChild('.test') testRef;` but i recieve the value as undefined

Comment: @ViewChild is not working directly with css selectors like classes and ids. But you can get around it via directives or you can just use plain JS `querySelector`s if you do not want to overcomplicate things.